# BLDC waterproofing for submergance

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, magnetics, hall-effect, potting

I have modified a number of brushless DC motors to make them work underwater. The motors are the type with hall effect sensors.

I did the following procedure on several motors, but the results have been inconsistent. Some of the motors work perfectly while others do not.

- I disassembled the motor, removed the rotor and bearings.
- Made a cylindrical blank, larger than the rotor diameter and smaller then the opening in the laminations. The blank was designed to be centred and the bearing housing surfaces were protected.
- I coated the blank in release agent and inserted into the motor and locked it in place.
- I filled the motor with potting epoxy so that the windings,
  laminations and hall effect sensors are completely enclosed and waterproof.
- After the epoxy has set I removed the blank, the surface of
  the epoxy was smooth and concentric with the axis of the motor.
- I assembled the motor again. The rotor turns freely by hand so the
  problem is not mechanical.

Some of the motors are working perfectly same as before the stator was potted in epoxy while some of the motors not working properly. The problematic motors no longer self start and are not as strong (lower unloaded RPM).

Any suggestions on what is causing these problems? Is there a fundamental problem with this approach or in principle at least should it work? Any suggestions for trouble shooting?

Epoxy type is: [MG Chemicals 832B-375ML](https://www.mgchemicals.com/products/potting-compounds/epoxy-potting/black-epoxy/).

Comment: Oh, so you did. My bad. In any case, you can spin it up as a generator and scope the sensors and phase voltages. I hope you have a 6 channel scope, or at least a 4 channnel.

Comment: @DKNguyen I've edited the question and deleted some of the comments.

Comment: Do you know what the shrinkage ratio of your epoxy is?

Comment: @brhans, I don't know. What problems might that cause? What would be the indications?

Comment: Sensor misalignment

Comment: ^^ or under extreme circumstances broken connections.

Comment: I can see that sensor misalignment might cause problems with starting. Would that also explain the lower power?

Comment: @HubertB Everything would be out of synch then. That's why I said to scope the waveforms. It's like pistons in an engine misfiring.

Comment: Aside your bad luck, I used that Black Epoxy to attach magnets of my experimental BLDC motors (pancake). It was kept in a box for many years (10?). Last time when I opened the box, several magnets were lose and sticking together.